# JPA Hibernate How to cascade remove from a child to parent

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

My application consists of Meal and Student models in which Meal is the parent and Student is the child. Now I want to cascade from child to parent, so when a student is deleted the corresponding meals are automatically deleted aswell.

Right now cascading is working, but only from parent to child. So when i delete a Meal from the database the corresponding Student is deleted aswell.

Is there any way I could turn this around?

My models look as following:

**Meal.Java**

```
@Entity
public class Meal {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  private Student mealCook;

  private String mealName;

  private int mealPrice;
```

**Student.Java**

```
@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String studentName;

@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "mealCook",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<Meal> meals = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Remove `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` from the ManyToOne. It makes no sense on a ManyToXxx association. Removing the student would fail due to all the foreign key constraints from the other meals to the deleted student. You don't want to delete a student every time you delete on of his meals.

Comment: I had that one in just to test if cascade remove was working properly from parent to child which it did but i want it to work from child to parent, so when i delete a student the meal should be removed aswell. Any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: You already have. cascade=ALL will delete all the meals ot the student when you delete the student. If it doesn't, then either you have an exception and you should post the code causing it and its stack trace, or you have a bug in your code, and you should post it, too.

Comment: It seems to be working properly now, I was deleting the student directly from the database which wasn't triggering the cascade apparantly. Deleting the student from the application using CRUD deleted the meal like it should. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The cascading is done by Hibernate, not by the database. The database doesn't know anything about your Java code.